# git lfs not recognizing tracked file types

Tags: git, github, unity-game-engine, git-lfs

I am trying to push my files to my repository (I am making a game design portfolio). Originally, it told me that my .unity3d files were too large to push (over 100 MB), so I downloaded git lfs. It seems to be working fine but it still says that my file is too large.

This is what resulted when I ran `$git push -u origin master`
(I had to edit the links so stack overflow would let me post the message).

Git LFS: (1 of 1 files) 163.57 MB / 163.57 MB
Counting objects: 15, done.

Delta compression using up to 8 threads.

Compressing objects: 100% (12/12), done.

Writing objects: 100% (15/15), 14.42 MiB | 2.64 MiB/s, done.

Total 15 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (2/2), done.

`remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com`.

remote: `error: Trace: 6b94a0d15a14a7da617866b684de1b8e`

remote: `error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g` for more information.

remote: error: File Star Bomber Web Build.unity3d is 163.57 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB

To https://github.com/IanGRap/IanGRap.github.io.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)

error: failed to push some refs to = 'https://github.com/IanGRap/IanGRap.github.io.git'

The file refered too on the first line appears to be the one I was originally referring to, as they are the same size. But if git lfs recognizes it, why is it later saying that the file is too large?

Here is what I have git lfs currently tracking.

Listing tracked paths

```
*.unity3d (.gitattributes)
```

I was worried git lfs might not work with unity3d files for whatever reason, but it almost looks like it recognizes it then forgets it did? I'm still really new to all things git hub so does anybody know if I may be doing something wrong?

Comment: why do you want to versioncontrol your webbuild?

Comment: That was just me going overboard on the tracking, I don't really have a goal with it.

Comment: I went back and edited it out to simplify things.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. Turns out My file had already been saved to git independent of lfs. Just adding the file type to tracking doesn't move specific files to be tracked by lfs, they have to start that way.

Comment: Same with .gitignore - the files have to be initially committed after the relevant configuration file is committed